# Why is my face mesh completely flat unlike the tutorial guys?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I moved the vertices in the front view in the X axis only using <kbd>g</kbd> like he said in the video at 15:25-15:37 (https://youtu.be/bx953Hl6Eu8?t=745)

However mine is flat like the picture and his is in the shape of a face in the video at 15:38 (https://youtu.be/bx953Hl6Eu8?t=938)

If you don't want to use the links, The video is:
"Blender Character Modeling Tutorial - For Absolute Beginners - Part 1"
from this youtuber: "Blender Art"

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Apart from that the statement in the video to move on "X axis only in front view" and "Y axis only in side view" is nonsense since you have to move on Z axis as well if you don't want a straight line - of course his mesh is in the shape of a face, because he is not only working in front view, but in side view as well. First adjusting vertices in one view and aligning them with the refrence in this direction, then tweaking the positions in the other view to align them with that reference... he is not doing everything in front view and the side view aligns magically by itself.

Comment: "However mine is flat like the picture"

There is no picture.
I don#t know how your results looks like, so i have no clue how to help.